# How to convert an external html file to PDF in c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created a web form on asp.net. The idea is that i convert a html file which is filled with the inputs from the WebForm.aspx into a pdf file and download it on a button click event. I have tried using IronPDF, but every time i clik on the button it just loads the webform again and again. This is the code:

```
    protected void btnConvertToPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Render = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
        var PDF = Render.RenderHTMLFileAsPdf("C:/Users/silvio/source/repos/WebFormSilvio/WebFormSilvio/Views/HtmlPage1.html");
        var Outpupath = "C:/Users/silvio/Downloads/Form1.pdf";
        PDF.SaveAs(Outpupath);

    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUploadCtrl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadCtrl.FileName);
                FileUploadCtrl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload Status: Dosja u ngarkua!";               
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Dosja nuk u ngarkua. Ndodhi nje error:" + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it loads the form again because this is due to something called `PostBack` you need to understand what postbacks are and why controls in asp.net trigger automatic postbacks also you can set autopost back on buttons to false. and create javascript to call your button click events also in your `Page_Load` event you need to put some breakpoints or add some `if( !IsPostBack){  }` checks and try handling it that way or google the `__DoPostBack` function and bind to your btnUpload Event

Answer (score 2):

I think you should stream your file pdf for the client:

```
  var Render = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
  var PDF = Render.RenderHTMLFileAsPdf("C:/Users/silvio/source/repos/WebFormSilvio/WebFormSilvio/Views/HtmlPage1.html");
  var Outpupath = "C:/Users/silvio/Downloads/Form1.pdf";
  PDF.SaveAs(Outpupath);

  //attach the file to the reponse and return it
  var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(outputPath);
  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", outputPath));
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
  Response.WriteFile(outputPath);
  Response.End();
```

If your pdf is big, you should use `Response.TransmitFile`, instead of `Response.WriteFile`.

Comment: `Response.TransmitFile` - So Clever, i will remember that for later !